# REST API сервис

Tags: python, rest

прохожу отбор в академию яндекса на курс backend разработки. Выдали задание по разработке REST API сервиса, который позволяет пользователям загружать и обновлять информацию о файлах и папках. Не имею ни малейшего понятия где по этой теме можно найти что-то полезное, в академию скорее всего не отберусь, т.к срок до 15го числа, но хотя бы для себя хочу изучить что-то новое. В общем, если есть какие-то гайды по этой теме, что да как(язык python, если что)

Comment: Почитайте про `flask`, там всё просто. А обращаться к сервису можно через `requests`.

Comment: Задача по смыслу похожа на DAV - но DAV - это крайне переусложнённая штука.

Comment: Как альтернативу flask еще посмотрите FastAPI